# Adding event listner to React Native ART component

Tags: javascript, android, ios, d3.js, react-native

Is it possible to add event listener to ReactNative ART component? I have created bar graph using React Native ART and d3.js. Now, I wanted each bar to get highlighted on tapping that bar. But since bar is converted into path by using d3-path, I am providing this path to d attribute of Shape component of React Native ART. So, if I want to add functionality on tapping, how can I add event listener to this component?

Answer (score 0):

you can add an component above the art component to listener the touch event